# How can I disable the default composer install in CircleCI?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, circleci

I have a product in CircleCI that has a `composer.json`. By default, when this file is present, CircleCI will run a `composer install`. However, I don't want this, since I'm spawning a docker container in which I will run all my composer stuff.

So my question is basically:

**How can I disable CircleCI's default behaviour and make it 'ignore' my `composer.json` file?**

Comment: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/disable-automatic-environment-requirements-detection-and-installs/4093 ?